# How to display name on mouseover on a div where element is loaded from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two boxes with images of `bird` and `fish` in them.

I have a `.boxleft` and `.boxright`, fish can be dragged and dropped to `.boxleft` and  bird can be dragged and dropped to `.boxright`.

I have an array `tempimages[]` which get value  of `selected items` when function `rvalue()` executes and tempimage[] value get deleted on each sucessful drop.

**My problem** is that i **want to display the name** of the **animal** when i **hover mouse on it**.

ie, if `i mouse over on pigeon` it should `show pigeon` on `top portion` (**like a comment box**).

How to achieve this?

```js
var array2 = [];

/** Update items with TYPE */
var items = [{
    label: 'pigeon',
    type: 'avian',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/VWfrPmS/pigeon.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'goldfish',
    type: 'aquatic',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/JrpWxYZ/goldfish.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'parrot',
    type: 'avian',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Y820hz4/parrot.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'fshark',
    type: 'aquatic',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/m0rtL1L/shark.png'
  },
];
var tempimages = [];
array2 = items.slice();
var item;

function rvalue() {
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

    item = array2[index];
    //console.log(item);
    try {

      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;

      ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.url;
      // ptags[index].style.visibility = "hidden";

      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
     
      if($(boxtags[index]).find("p").length === 0){
         $(boxtags[index]).append(ptags[index])
      }
      tempimages.push({
        data: item,
        index: index
      });

    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }  
  //console.log(tempimages);
}

rvalue();


function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var pText = $("#" + data).children()[0].id;

  // Get the label
  var label = $.trim($("#" + data).text().toLowerCase());

  // Check the item type
  var isBird = !!items.find(i => i.label.toLowerCase() === label && i.type === 'avian');

  if (ev.target.className === 'boxleft' && !isBird) {

  } else if (ev.target.className === 'boxright' && isBird) {

  } else {
    alert('Wrong box for the selected item');
    return false;
  }

  $("#" + pText).removeClass("hidden");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(pText));
  // ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
  
  var removeByAttr = function(tempimages, index, value){
  var i = tempimages.length;
  while(i--){
    if( tempimages[i] 
      && tempimages[i].hasOwnProperty(index) 
      && (arguments.length > 2 && tempimages[i][index] === value ) ){ 
        tempimages.splice(i,1);
  array2.splice(i,1);

      }
   }
   return tempimages;
}
  
  
  var index = items.findIndex(i => i.label.toLowerCase() === label)
  removeByAttr(tempimages, 'index', index)
 
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {  
            rvalue();  
            $(".boxleft,.boxright").html("")
        }
  
 
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3vh;
  left: -20.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3vh;
  left:10.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box2 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: 0.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box3 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: 20.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box4 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.boxleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.3vh;
  left: -25.98vw;
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.boxright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.3vh;
  left: 25.98vw;
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

.boxleft p {
  font-size: calc(4vw);
  height: 4vh;
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.boxright p {
  font-size: calc(4vw);
  height: 4vh;
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="box1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name2" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name3" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name4" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxleft" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="2"></div>
  <div class="boxright" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="3"></div>
```

i have tried

> div.hidden { display:none; }
>
> /* Target the hidden div when the target >div is being hovered over */
>
> `#box1:hover + div.hidden` {
>   display:block;
>   }

but didnt give the effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array2 = [];

/** Update items with TYPE */
var items = [{
    label: 'pigeon',
    type: 'avian',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/VWfrPmS/pigeon.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'goldfish',
    type: 'aquatic',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/JrpWxYZ/goldfish.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'parrot',
    type: 'avian',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Y820hz4/parrot.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'fshark',
    type: 'aquatic',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/m0rtL1L/shark.png'
  },
];
var tempimages = [];
array2 = items.slice();
var item;

function rvalue() {
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

    item = array2[index];
    //console.log(item);
    try {

      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;

      ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.url;
      // ptags[index].style.visibility = "hidden";
  boxtags[index].title=item.label;
      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
    
      if($(boxtags[index]).find("p").length === 0){
         $(boxtags[index]).append(ptags[index])
      }
      tempimages.push({
        data: item,
        index: index
      });

    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }  
  //console.log(tempimages);
}

rvalue();


function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var pText = $("#" + data).children()[0].id;

  // Get the label
  var label = $.trim($("#" + data).text().toLowerCase());

  // Check the item type
  var isBird = !!items.find(i => i.label.toLowerCase() === label && i.type === 'avian');

  if (ev.target.className === 'boxleft' && !isBird) {

  } else if (ev.target.className === 'boxright' && isBird) {

  } else {
    alert('Wrong box for the selected item');
    return false;
  }

  $("#" + pText).removeClass("hidden");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(pText));
  // ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
  
  var removeByAttr = function(tempimages, index, value){
  var i = tempimages.length;
  while(i--){
    if( tempimages[i] 
      && tempimages[i].hasOwnProperty(index) 
      && (arguments.length > 2 && tempimages[i][index] === value ) ){ 
        tempimages.splice(i,1);
  array2.splice(i,1);

      }
   }
   return tempimages;
}
  
  
  var index = items.findIndex(i => i.label.toLowerCase() === label)
  removeByAttr(tempimages, 'index', index)
 
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {  
            rvalue();  
            $(".boxleft,.boxright").html("")
        }
  
 
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3vh;
  left: -20.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3vh;
  left:10.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box2 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: 0.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box3 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: 20.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box4 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.boxleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.3vh;
  left: -25.98vw;
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.boxright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.3vh;
  left: 25.98vw;
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

.boxleft p {
  font-size: calc(4vw);
  height: 4vh;
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.boxright p {
  font-size: calc(4vw);
  height: 4vh;
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}
div[title]:hover:after {
   content: attr(title);
   padding: 4px 8px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   z-index: 20px;
   background:black;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="box1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name2" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name3" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <p name="values" id="name4" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxleft" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="2"></div>
  <div class="boxright" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="3"></div>
```

Set `title` attribute for enable default tooltip. You customize its appearence using css.

Comment: boxtags[index].title=item.label; its effective thanks brother